# How to set action type in extraReducer using reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm learning React with reduxjs/toolkit and i created thunk but i have problem with typing.

I'm getting this error: `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<MovieModel>[]'`

interface and type

```
interface StateModel {
  movies: MovieModel[];
  isFetching: boolean;
  errorMessage: any;
}

type MyApiResponse = {
  [key: string]: MovieModel[];
};
```

My thunk:

```
export const fetchMoviesAsync = createAsyncThunk('movies/fetchMoviesAsync', async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://react-movies-b6b21-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/movies.json'
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Error fetching data ‍');
    }
    const data = await response.json();

    const transformedData = Object.entries(data as MyApiResponse).map(([key, value]) => {
      return {
        ...value,
        id: key,
      };
    });
    return transformedData;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
});
```

Movie Slice:

```
export const moviesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movies/fetchMoviesAsync',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchMoviesAsync.pending, state => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchMoviesAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.movies = action.payload; // this line is getting error
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchMoviesAsync.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.errorMessage = action.payload;
    });
  },
});
```

I've tried to set type for my thunk like this:

```
export const fetchMoviesAsync = createAsyncThunk<MovieModel[]>('movies/fetchMoviesAsync', async () => {}
```

but then i getting other error which is:

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<MovieModel[], void, {}>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action type is not set in `extraReducer` - `extraReducer` uses the action type of your `createAsyncThunk`.

You would have to do

```
createAsyncThunk<YourExpectedReturnType>('movies/fetchMoviesAsync', // ...
```

For more info see [usage with TypeScript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk).

On a sidenote, your `return error` there would go into the fulfiled case, not the rejected case. You probably want to use `rejectWithValue`.

Comment: I've tried that as i mentioned above

Comment: Because you are also returning things from your payload creator that are not `MovieModel`  in your `return error;`. You have to use `rejectWithValue` for errors and not just return them (as that would put them in the fulfilled case)